# in Android google vision OCR how I can determine the accuracy of recognition

Tags: android, android-vision, google-vision

In google vision OCR, under Android, how I find and know what was the accuracy of a recognized text?

Comment: I believe you are looking for Confidence, not Accuracy. OCR is just a AI software, that can do mistakes. It always provides you with best guess, but it does not know if this guess is correct or not. If it knew that, why would it return wrong answer anyway? :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no function available in the [API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/text/package-summary) that gives you the confidence score from the OCR.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate accuracy, human intervention will be necessary. A software program cannot know when it is incorrect just like that, otherwise it would correct itself.

So you will have to write a program for this specific purpose. In that program, you will give the OCR, a number of test images to OCR. With those test images, you will also have to manually associated what is supposed to be the 'correct result'. You can then compare this manually written text with what the OCR detected. As a result, you can calculate the accuracy percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You will not able to determine the accuracy of the text detection using google vision.

But **you can increase the accuracy**, if it kind of static documents like business cards.

**This is not for cloud vision.**

**You just add boundaries for the text detection**. when you capture the image then take the image boundaries and take separate bitmap according to the boundaries and then convert to Gray colour bitmap, then fetch the text from the seaprate bitmaps.

If the image is very dark or water marks or colour images then **apply contrast** for that bitmap. it will increase the accuracy.